# TypeError: render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template_name'

Tags: python, django

I created simple form register user but something is wrong. This is my django project:

settings.py
[image]

account/urls.py
[image]

forms.py
[image]

views.py
[image]

Directories:
[image]

error:
[image]
[image]

I don't understand this issue. I use render(request, 'name_template', {}) but django request  name_template. What did I do wrong?

Sorry for my english but I still learn ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your path it should be

```
path('register/, views.register, ....)
```

Comment: You're my HERO. Thank you. Next time I must peruse code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your TEMPLATES section in settings.py. It looks something like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]
```

Check if you have path specified to your templates in 'DIR' key.
If not, then add specified path to your templates folder.

```
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'account','templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIR': [TEMPLATES_DIR,]
    },
]
```

Documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#templates

Comment: At the beginning I thought that bug is here. But another views working for example: login, logout ... . Finally I found bug but anyway thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

you're mapped a wrong view inside urls.py

```
path('register/', views.render, name='register'),
```

Change it to

```
path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
```